# wget shows 404 not found while the page is live

Tags: linux, http-status-code-404, wget

This looks simple but I don't know how to fix.

Open the following URL in your browser:

```
https://ecomm.sella.it/gestpay/gestpayws/WSCryptDecrypt.asmx?WSDL
```

This seems working and this will download and XML WSDL in your browser.

But on our linux server when I try to wget the same URL it return with 404-Not found error:

```
wget https://ecomm.sella.it/gestpay/gestpayws/WSCryptDecrypt.asmx?WSDL
```

At the same time when I try to wget google or hotmail it just works fine. But this WSDL URL returns with 404 error code. Looks like this is some kind of caching issue.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I get a 404 on both browser and wget. I think your browser has cached instead?

Comment: I cleared my browser's cache so many times. tried with different browsers and requested my friends on different locations to test this. and the same URL was working everywhere without any 404 error.  After your comment I tried to test this on an online proxy and it is working there as well.

Comment: Is it possible that for large website's some URL is working in an area/region like UK but not in another region like ASIA something like propagation issue? But this was working an hour ago on same machine.

Comment: @MalikAhmedKhanAwan this is totally locally based. It opens for Netherlands and Germany's proxy but gives 404 for USA's proxy (apart from my own location)

Comment: @Samar you are right. This is locally based. I checked this URL now on https://www.uptrends.com/tools/uptime . and it says that this API is not available at the moment in different regions including Rome. Please Answer to this question and then I'll mark it as the Right Answer. :)

Comment: @MalikAhmedKhanAwan yes, correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is totally locally based. It opens for Netherlands and Germany's proxy but gives 404 for USA's proxy (apart from my own location).

Answer (score -1):

404 is a client side err, if you don't have any typo before query(?) then it would simply mean the server you connected may not have the file you are trying to download. There may be regional servers, the ones missing a deploy,  try wget from the same regional host if you have where it worked from browser.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is not client side err. 404 is always server side error. If the server doesn't find a document it returns the 404 status code. And finally we figured out that this is not server or caching issue. the API itself is not accessible in some regions across the world.